# How to store several data in this case with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sending an array of data with axios that looks like this :

```
originalData:Object
  19:"ae"
  20:"aze"
  21:"aze"
  22:"aze"
  23:"aze"
  24:"aez"
  79:"az"
  80:"aza"
  81:"az"
  83:"az"
```

Each id corresponds to the id of a question. And each text of the id corresponds to his answer.

My table `answers` contains this structure :

`id`, `answer`, `user_id`, `question_id`

I would like to create new lines in the database for each answer. The `id` must be stored in the column `question_id` and the text in the column`answer`

I tried something like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        $finalArray = [];

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            array_push($finalArray, [
               'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
               'question_id' => ??,
               'answer' => ??
            ]);
        }

        Answer::insert($finalArray);
    }
```

I don't know if it's the right method. In any case, I don't know how to get the `id` and the text of the question in this case.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to show/print what `$key` and `$value` look from your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            Answer::create([
                 'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                 'question_id' => $key, // $key will be 19, 20...
                 'answer' => $value // $value 'ae', 'aze' ...
            ]);
        }
    }
```

This should work fine. If you have any error provide it here.

Good luck!